# how to handle with string while writing in csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

[image]i'm trying to write in csv file i have two value in my list [string,int] and this is my code

```
prod = [['Enveloppes Esquisse adh\xe9sives', 1.85], 
        ['Enveloppes adh\xe9sives Esquisse', 1.1], 
        ['Enveloppes adh\xe9sives Esquisse', 1.1], 
        ['Enveloppes adh\xe9sives Esquisse', 1.85], 
        ['Pochettes kraft Esquisse', 0.95], 
        ['Pochettes kraft Esquisse', 1.75]]

cw = csv.writer(open("nv.csv", 'w'), delimiter=';')
    cw.writerow(['Produit', 'Prix'])
    for row in prod:
        cw.writerow( [row[0],row[1]] )
```

but i get 'enveloppes' in row then esquisse in other row not all the string in one row
can anyone help me ?
my csv file should contain two rows, one for 'Enveloppes Esquisse adh\xe9sives' and one for '1,85'

Comment: Could you show what is your desired output?

Comment: In this case, `cw.writerow([row[0],row[1]])` has the same effect as `cw.writerow(row)`.

Comment: Please post the whole output, it's still not clear what you actually want here.

Comment: as you can see in the attached photo, 'crayon de couleur esquisse' should be in 'Produit' row

Comment: @imoum If you wrote the file as in my answer then, when opening it in the OpenOffice you should in the `Text Import` dialog, `Separated by` section check only the `semicolon` option. All other options should be unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation say:

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode,
>   but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL
>   characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the
>   encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like
>   UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.

Since your strings are either `cp1250` or `cp1252` (I cannot tell from the sample) encoded byte string and not unicode strings, that's should be OK. You should just open your file in binary mode:

```
import io
import csv
prod = [['Enveloppes Esquisse adh\xe9sives', 1.85],
        ['Enveloppes adh\xe9sives Esquisse', 1.1],
        ['Enveloppes adh\xe9sives Esquisse', 1.1],
        ['Enveloppes adh\xe9sives Esquisse', 1.85],
        ['Pochettes kraft Esquisse', 0.95],
        ['Pochettes kraft Esquisse', 1.75]
        ]

with io.open('nv.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['Produit', 'Prix'])
    for row in prod:
        writer.writerow(row)
```